# Do you know a textbook that explains the series representations of the prime counting function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

On [this page](http://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/PrimePi/06/01/) from Wolfram.Research I found 13 different series representations of the Prime Counting Function, $\pi(x)$ or PrimePi[x].

I tried to find a textbook using Google Books ( analytic number theory ) which explains any of these representations. I couldn't find any.

Do you know a textbook that explains the ( preferably all 13 (*) ) series representations of the prime counting function as mentioned on Wolfram.Research?

(*) Except maybe the 9th which counts numbers which are qualified prime (...).

Comment: The 13th concerns the nontrival zeros of the Riemann zeta-function, and you can find a proof for that in the famous book "Riemann's Zeta Function" by H.M.Edwards. All the rest are not practical, I guess; not practical in the sense that you need to know all the primes up to x to get a value for $\pi(x)$. I think I found a "proof" of one of those formulas in the book "Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Hardy and Littlewood.

Comment: I have the book by H&L, will go through that again. Perhaps I should post questions about the individual series ( practical or not ). What do you think?

Comment: I found one argument at the back of H&L, if I remember correctly. If there are some practical research questions about them, I think it is okay to post them.

Comment: The first series is (simply) an application of Wilson's Theorem. - Going through all the series might be quite an interesting exercise (revision if you like) of basic number theory. The first series is computationally highly impractical as you suspected.